# Ruby:#error: undefined method `pop'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Newbie and working on someone else's code. This is our yaml

```
current_colleges_for_degrees:
  cahs:
    label: 'college one'
  com:
    label: 'college two'

additional_current_colleges:
  another:
    label: 'another College'
  yet:
    label: 'yet another'
  library:
    label: 'Libraries'
```

then we have a helper file with this:

```
def sorted_college_list_for_generic_works
    list = COLLEGE_AND_DEPARTMENT["current_colleges_for_degrees"].merge(
      COLLEGE_AND_DEPARTMENT["additional_current_colleges"]
    )
    list.keys.collect do |k|
      list[k]["label"]
    end.sort << "Other"
end
```

I need to take that and make a new method called student_works- BUT- I need to remove the last item in the array: "Libraries" so...

```
def sorted_college_list_for_student_works
    list = COLLEGE_AND_DEPARTMENT["current_colleges_for_degrees"].merge(
      COLLEGE_AND_DEPARTMENT["additional_current_colleges"]
    )
   ***list.pop***
    list.keys.collect do |k|
      list[k]["label"]
end.sort << "Other"
end
```

Cant get it to work however...the error is:
" #error: undefined method `pop' for ..."

as a newbie, I dont totally understand what the error means. Edit: is there an easier way to accomplish this? Open to suggestions as I gain knowledge!

end

Comment: Lucky you! What's more fun than working on someone else's code? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: yeah, sucks doesnt it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list` isn't an array, it's a hash. Hashes don't define the `#pop` method and that's why you're getting the error.

To delete an item from a hash you can use the `#delete` method and pass the key.

```
list.delete("library")
```

Comment: OK, but when I insert that into the code above I get 
"comparison of String with nil failed"

Answer (score 1):

As @Jack pointed out, you're working with a list not an array. My question would be why do you need to remove the last item? and if you already know the last key?

I would go this way:

`my_list.delete(my_list.keys.last)`